# Why don't Word and Excel save files on exit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

**Why don't Word and Excel save files on exit?**

It started about a month ago.  Whenever I exit either Excel or Word, they offer to save the changes and I select `Yes`.  Yet the files remain unchanged.

If I manually save the file, it saves the changes.  I have reinstalled Office, but it still behaves the same way.

- I am on Windows 10 and Office Pro 2016.
- I am not saving to the cloud
- I don't see any errors
- There are no add-ons installed ever.  And I had reinstalled Office
- There is nothing in the Event Log
- Note **Save As** works.  But I keep forgetting to do that.  I just lost an article I spent an hour writing.
- Because **Save As** works, there are no issues with permissions or anti-virus
- There are no files in the Autorecover folder, which is set to every 5 minutes
- Malwarebytes has no recorded events on it.
- It is not being saved in the Documents folder

Comment: see if the [link][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/issue-when-save-excel-workbooks?tabs=third-party] helps

Comment: BTW, a likely cause is an unhandled exception on application closure -- i.e., the app crashes before the document could be saved. Look to any Office add-on, since you've already reinstalled MS Office.

Comment: @Derby9421, I had a look, but all of those reasons would still be valid when I do **Save As**, yet that works.  And I don't see any errors.

Comment: Here is my guess.  You are likely not saving the file you opened by a copy of that file.  This might be for a variety of reasons.  Have you looked in the folder configured as the location for temporary documents? Are you logged into a Microsoft Account within Office?